# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, babel, webpack4

> Error in ./REST_R/frontend/src/components/App.js 7:4
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Вот такая ошибка, ломаю голову как исправить.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }

    ]
}
};
```

файл **.babelrc**

```
{
"presets": [
    "env", "react"
],
"plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
]
}
```

Сам файл **App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Table from "./Table"

const App = () => (
    <DataProvider endpoint="api/lead/"
                  render={data => <Table data={data} /> }/>
 );

const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");

wrapper ? ReactDom.render(<App/>, wrapper) : null;
```

И файл **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "superlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./REST_R/frontend/src/index.js --output ./REST_R/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./REST_R/frontend/src/index.js --output ./REST_R/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "weak-key": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в файле *App.js*, вот в этом месте:

```
const App = () => (
    <DataProvider endpoint="api/lead/"
                  render={data => <Table data={data} /> }/>
 );
```

Компонент с поддержкой `render` пропсы принимает функцию, которая возвращает React элемент и вызывает этот метод вместо реализации собственной логики визуализации, то есть метода `render`. Библиотеки, в которых используются функции рендеринга, ну или `render` пропса - это [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) и [Downshift](https://github.com/paypal/downshift). Почитать можно на официальном сайте документации по React: [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). Поэтому вопрос к вашему `DataProvider` компоненту, есть ли у него такая пропса `render`, и принимает ли она функцию, и имеется ли необходимая обработка внутри этого компонента.

И немного не по вашему вопросу, в качестве рекомендации хотелось бы показать, как делать более читабельные переносы:

```
const App = () => (
  <DataProvider
    endpoint="api/lead/"
    render={data => <Table data={data} /> }
  />
);
```